# Batch file to compare 2 directories and get names of files that are different [dos]

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I will have 2 directories, folder1 with a set files list, and folder2 with the same set file list but with more files. I need to get folder2's "other files"
Does something exist like file compare (fc) for directories to return the differences?

**EDIT** I am currently creating 2 lists using `dir` and then doing a file compare. Now I just need to parse the output of the `fc` to only contain the file names.

```
fc /a "C:\whatever\text1.txt" "C:\whatever\text2.txt" >> "C:\whatever\differences.txt"
```

Comment: I don't know of anything (free) and googling didn't bring up much, but you could always write your own console app using C#, JAVA, whatever, and call it from your batch program. That's probably what I'd do.

Comment: Yeah I know I could do it in C, but I already have some batch stuff written, I was just trying to find a quick solution.

Comment: I did one in batch language (see answer) I forgot to say it's called *dirc.bat* I wonder, don't you have vbscript or jscript available, since you used the [windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host#Version_history) tag?

Comment: I could write this in another language, but its a specific need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First do a `dir /s` on both folders. Then use `fc /a` to compare the results.

For anything better than that (depending in your needs) you'll need a specialized tool. For instance have a look at `Windiff` or `WinMerge`.

Comment: Idneed, there is nothing useful for this built-in in Windows. If you can use a GUI interactive program, there are many, but I love the highly configurable "Synchronize dirs" feature of Total Commander. If it needs to run at the command-line, I woud use cwrsync. If you only want to see the differences without actually synchronizing, use the --dry-run and --verbose switches to cwrsync.

Answer (score 6):

**Batchfile**

```
@echo off
if "%2" == "" GOTO Usage

cd /D %1
if errorlevel 1 goto usage

for %%x in (*.*) do if NOT exist %2\%%x echo missing %2\%%x
cd /D %2
for %%x in (*.*) do if NOT exist %1\%%x echo missing %1\%%x

goto end

:usage
echo Usage %0 dir1 dir2
echo where dir1 and dir2 are full paths
:end
```

**Usage**

Environment:

```
F:\so>dir /s dir1 dir2
 Volume in drive F is WIN2K
 Volume Serial Number is 921E-EC47

 Directory of F:\so\dir1

2010-11-22  10:33       <DIR>          .
2010-11-22  10:33       <DIR>          ..
2010-11-22  10:33                   13 a
2010-11-22  10:33                   13 b
2010-11-22  10:33                   13 c
               3 File(s)             39 bytes

 Directory of F:\so\dir2

2010-11-22  10:33       <DIR>          .
2010-11-22  10:33       <DIR>          ..
2010-11-22  10:33                   13 a
2010-11-22  10:33                   13 b
2010-11-22  10:33                   13 c
2010-11-22  10:33                   13 D
2010-11-22  10:33                   13 E
               5 File(s)             65 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               5 File(s)             65 bytes
               2 Dir(s)     219,848,704 bytes free

F:\so>
```

Running:

```
F:\so\dir1>dirc f:\so\dir1 f:\so\dir2

F:\so\dir1>dirc f:\so\dir1 f:\so\dir2
missing f:\so\dir1\D
missing f:\so\dir1\E

F:\so\dir2>
```

Comment: very cool solution but I would like to know how this can be expanded. I want to find all files in directory and subdirectories for dir1 and then find if the file(s) also exist in directory/subdirectory for dir2.